# "date" type inside Json schema

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jsonschema

I have next Json schema:

```
string jsonSchema = @"{
  ""properties"": {
                ""dateOfEvent"": {
                    ""type"": ""date"",
                }
            }
        }";
```

and I want to validate input JSON by this schema. I trying to use [Microsoft.Json.Schema](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Json.Schema/) and [Microsoft.Json.Schema.Validation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Json.Schema.Validation/), but I have: *"Exception of type 'Microsoft.Json.Schema.SchemaValidationException' was thrown."* on next line of my code:

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(jsonSchema))
{
    var schema = SchemaReader.ReadSchema(reader, string.Empty);
    //some code for validation
}
```

Can anybody explain me what's wrong and how I can use this jsonSchema for JSON validation?

Comment: I would suggest you could try Json.net. Refer to these links - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm

Comment: Date is not a valid type value.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message said, the date is an invalid JSON schema type. For the Date property, you could use the `string` type and the `date` format. Code like this:

```
    "date": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "date"
    }
```

[Note] By using the above method, since the date is a string type, it seems that it will not check whether the date is a valid or not. If you want to validate the date value, you could try to [Custom JSON validation rules](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/CustomJsonValidators.htm).